# using parameter in a datatable in vb2012

Tags: mysql, datagridview, datatable

I populated a DataGridView from DataTable.

I want to have the option to view a certain client  within the datagridview.

in the DataTable query, When I use an integer type parameter: the query works well.

```
SELECT        CODINT, Apelido, EMPRESA, NOME, RUA_NUM, BAIRRO, CIDADE, CEP, EST, LJA, ESENCIAL, ASS
FROM            V_Clientes1
WHERE        (CODINT = @vcod)
ORDER BY CODINT
```

In the query parameters window I enter

```
@vcod = 10149
```

and it returns the desired row and it is OK.

But using a string type parameter returns the no rows.

```
SELECT        CODINT, Apelido, EMPRESA, NOME, RUA_NUM, BAIRRO, CIDADE, CEP, EST, LJA, ESENCIAL, ASS
FROM            V_Clientes1
WHERE        (EMPRESA LIKE @vemp)
ORDER BY EMPRESA
```

In the query parameters window I enter:
    `@vemp = SERIBRAS  or @vemp = 'SERIBRAS' or @vemp ="SERIBRAS"`  (the name is valid)

However, that particular query does not return any rows. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [wild cards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) e.g. the following example we want ContactTile starting with 'sa' but if you have the exact value use = instead of like.

[image]